# OneDrive API for reading, deleting and creating comments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

What *api.onedrive.com* endpoints can be used for reading, deleting and creating comments of documents stored in OneDrive?

```
var docId = "C382F44F3E2D3362!392363";
using (var http = new HttpClient()) {
    var json = await http.GetStringAsync($"https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/???{docId}???/comments");
    var comments = JObject.Parse(json);
    ...
}
```

I need to rewrite an app which use [Live SDK to manipulate OneDrive comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826524.aspx). Live SDK is deprecated now. I need an API which is currently supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneDrive is a cloud storage system, it doesn't support directly editing the files stored on it